# emacs で commandline から daemon が実行されているかを確認したい

Tags: emacs

普段開発に emacs を利用しています。 .emacs.d/init.el の中で、起動された emacs は server をスタートさせるようになっています。そして、 emacs (サーバー) プロセスを一つ起動した後に、それ以降は emacsclient でもってファイルの編集などを行っています。

emacs と emacsclient の両方を使い分けて普段作業しているのですが、これは少し面倒なので、状況に応じて適切な方のコマンドを実行するシェルを記述しようと思いました。

#### 質問

- コマンドライン上で、 emacs サーバーが今起動しているかどうかを判定する方法はありますか?

Comment: `server-running-p` を使って `emacsclient --eval '(server-running-p)' >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'running' || echo 'not started'` とか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@metropolis さんのコメントを参考に、次のようなスクリプトを記述しました。

```
#!/bin/sh

server_running_p() {
   emacsclient --eval '(server-running-p)' >/dev/null 2>&1
}

if server_running_p
then
    exec emacsclient -nw "$@"
else
    exec emacs -nw "$@"
fi
```

Comment: `emacsclient --eval '(server-running-p)'` はもっと単純に `emacsclient --eval t` でも大丈夫ですよね?